# Facebook Graph Api apprequests invite friends token ids not working

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the documentation here to create an "invite" apprequest. This is my code:

```
let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/apprequests", parameters: ["action_type": "INVITE", "message": "this guy is inviting you", "ids": "comma separated string of ids and invite tokens", HTTPMethod: "POST")
req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) in
})
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
<FBSDKGraphRequestConnection: 0x13e531300, 1 request(s): (
```

```
parameters: {
    "access_token" = <a_token>;
    "action_type" = INVITE;
    format = json;
    ids = 
"<invite_token>";
        "include_headers" = false;
        message = "this guy is inviting you";
        sdk = ios;
    }>
    )>
    Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid token: "me".  An ID has already been specified., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
        body =     {
            error =         {
                code = 2500;
                "fbtrace_id" = At0eLFYxe68;
                message = "Invalid token: \"me\".  An ID has already been specified.";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 400;
    }}
```